# Flag similar to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK in API 8

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My App has an Activity A which triggers B and B in turn triggers C.

Activity A is the launcher with the intent flag android:noHistory="true" in manifest file. This shows the splash screen. After 2 seconds it triggers B with the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. B triggers C normally without any intent flag. Now the Stack will have only the Activity C.

In Activity C, Whenever back is pressed It will trigger Activity B. Now the Stack should have the Activity B alone. It should not have any trace of other Activity.

I have used the following code in the Activity C. But the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is available only from API 11. The app should be supporting the devices from the API 8. Kindly assist me with the correct intent flags to achieve the explained scenario

### Code:

```
         Intent dragDropIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.DRAGDROP"); 
         dragDropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         dragDropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I agree that starting the Activity C without nohistory will help. But do t some technical constraints I don't want to do that. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C is always goes back to B, then you should not use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. Then when the user backpress in C, C would be finished by the OS and the stack now only has B.

Comment: yes but due to some technical constraint I am doing this. I mean  in other words I am trying to the restart the Activity B

Comment: You do not need any flag, just call finish() after you relaunch B from C.

Answer (score 5):

you are looking for this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
activity.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

use android compatibillity lib from google - found in the sdk.

or use `finish()`

Answer (score 3):

This flag is now available through the compatibility lib:

```
IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Hope this helps :)